Problem repeating a texture over a SCNShape in ARKit/SceneKit
I have a SCNShape and need to repeat a texture over the extrusion side. Some parts are ok, some not:
image from node
The texture:
Texture
The code:
private func makeShape(geometryPath: UIBezierPath, from normalizedPath: CGPath, image: CGImage) -> SCNNode {
        var extrusion = 0.04
        let geometry = SCNShape(path: geometryPath, extrusionDepth: extrusion)
        let node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)
        node.scale = SCNVector3(0.1428, 0.1428, 0.1428)
        node.castsShadow = true
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.isDoubleSided = false
        material.diffuse.contents = imagem
        let matInverse = SCNMaterial()
        matInverse.isDoubleSided = false
        matInverse.diffuse.contents = imagem
        let transv = SCNMatrix4Translate(SCNMatrix4MakeScale(-1, 1, 1), 1, 0, 0)
        matInverse.diffuse.contentsTransform = transv
        let matBoard = SCNMaterial()
        matBoard.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "vime")
        matBoard.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
        matBoard.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
        matBoard.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(1, 1, 0)
        matBoard.fillMode = .fill
        matBoard.isDoubleSided = true        
        geometry.materials = [material, matInverse, matBoard]
        return node
    }

How to repeat a texture over all extrusion side?
I need a texture over all the extrusion side.
I get a texture correct in some parts, but not all parts.
